# Separate last name 1st name and middle initial into one cell in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

I apologize for sending this question twice. The 1st one was a mess.

Every week I have a list of over 150 to 200 names that I need to separate last name 1st name and middle initial into one cell in Excel 2010. Example:

```
Column "A"  Reagan, Harry T.

Column "B"  Reagan HT
```

I have tried to combine these two formulas but have not been successful. Please Help.

```
=LEFT(A9,SEARCH(",",A9)-1) and 

=LEFT(A8)&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",A8)),MID(A8,FIND(" ",A8)+1,1),"")&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",A8,FIND(" ",A8)+1)),MID(A8,FIND(" ",A8,FIND(" ",A8)+1)+1,1),"")
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Rather than post a new question, just improve the original (or replace it with the content of this one).  If you want to stick with this one, delete the first (you should see "Delete" as an option at the bottom of the post).

Comment: What do you mean by "separate into one cell"? Is col A the source and Col B is the result you want?   What is the problem trying to combine the formulas (if the first formula produces a result to be used in the other formula, just use the first formula within the second where you want that result)?

Comment: Show ALL possible variants for source cell, and for each of them show desured result. Or the source is always `Xxxxxxx, Yyyyyy Z.` and according result is `Xxxxxxx YZ`? if so algo is: get (first space pos + 1) chars, concat (length - 1)-th char, then replace comma with empty string.

Comment: (1) I don’t see any big improvement from your original question.  If anything, this one is messier, because it shows columns as rows.  At least the original showed columns as columns.  (2) Help us help you.  What is the significance of the two formulas you are showing us?  What is the significance of the three components of the second one?  What output do they give?  How do you want to combine them?  Why can’t you just put a ``&`` between them?  And, I guess this is a typo, but why does the first one refer to `A9` and the second one to `A8`? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) I see the subexpression `FIND(" ",A8)` four times.  Learn to use helper columns!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine 2 formula's into one cell, you can simply use an **"&"** sign in between them.
In your case it will be

```
=LEFT(A9,SEARCH(",",A9)-1) & LEFT(A8)&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",A8)),MID(A8,FIND(" ",A8)+1,1),"")&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",A8,FIND(" ",A8)+1)),MID(A8,FIND(" ",A8,FIND(" ",A8)+1)+1,1),"")
```

Please comment below if you'd rather like to look for a simpler formula.

Comment: The OP's formula already contains ampersands, so I suspect lack of knowledge about the use of ampersands isn't the issue.  :-)

Comment: Thank you everybody for your comments and thank you Mr. Gangula, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the names enterted the same?

I.e.: last_name, first_name initial

If so, try this:

```
=CONCAT((LEFT($A$1,(FIND(",",$A$1,1)-1)))," ",(RIGHT(LEFT($A$1,(FIND(",",$A$1,1)+2)),1)),(LEFT(RIGHT($A$1,2),1)))
```